# node preview button not working

Tags: 7, nodes

The issue I am having is that when I try to preview the content of a node I have created by clicking the 'Preview' button the page just refreshes and the preview.

What I have tried

- Looking into permissions to do with viewing unpublished content.

Comment: Did you suggest any theme hook for the content type of that node ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your site local or not? Can you give a link?

   2. You use standart theme or custom?

Try to edit node type configuration → http://somesite.ltd/admin/structure/types/manage/content_type_machine_name. Before open link you must change somesite.ltd & content_type_machine_neme